# How to install tpm_tis.ko for CentOS6

Tags: centos, tpm

I am attempting to activate and use my TPM module on CentOS6.9 running kernel 2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64. All the tutorials I've found online start with installing tpm-tools and trousers, which I've done. But because there is no tmp_tis kernel module I am unable to proceed with actually connecting to the TPM or executing any tpm_* commands because it gives a communication error every time. I do know it is a TPM2.0 module if that makes a difference.

I'm sure it is something simple I've managed to overlook. Thanks.

EDIT:
tcsd module gives the following error when attempting to start

Jun 12 03:35:09 `<hostname>` TCSD TDDL[30907]: TrouSerS ioctl: (25) Inappropriate ioctl for device
Jun 12 03:35:09 `<hostname>` TCSD TDDL[30907]: TrouSerS Falling back to Read/Write device support.
Jun 12 03:35:09 `<hostname>` TCSD TCS[30907]: TrouSerS ERROR: TCS GetCapability failed with result = 0x1e

Comment: Have you enabled the TPM in your BIOS/firmware security menus, and also activated it?

Comment: Yes, the TPM is enabled in the BIOS. I can see /dev/tpm0 which from my reading is confirmation that the BIOS has correctly enabled the TPM.

Comment: Do you have `securityfs` mounted on `/sys/kernel/security`? Can you read the pcrs in `/sys/class/misc/tpm0/device/pcrs`? Have you been able to start `tcsd`?

Comment: There is nothing in or mounted to /sys/kernel/security. I don't have a /sys/class/misc/tpm0 folder. I added the tcsd start error to the post. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever make progress here? I am experiencing the same thing with CentOS7.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, and believe that Trousers (`tcsd`) does not support TPM 2.0. See [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/trousers/mailman/message/35229431/) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/tcsd.htm).

That said, I have installed `tpm2-tss` and `tpm2-tools` (with `yum`) and am hoping for luck with these packages. If I have success here I will update this response.

Here are a few links I am starting off with in case anyone else is stuck here:

- [tpm2-tools github](https://github.com/01org/tpm2-tools)
- [tpm2-tss github](https://github.com/01org/tpm2-tss)
- [free pdf on tpm 2.0](https://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4302-6584-9)